# are refs overriden or inherited in extjs?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc, extjs4.2

i had this parent class : assume its on correct syntax (views aliases, stores and xtypes):

```
    Ext.define('myParent' {
       extend : 'Ext.app.Controller',

refs : [{
        ref : 'formwindow',
        selector : 'forms-formwindow'
    }, {
        ref : 'mainForm',
        selector : '#mainForm'
    }],

    });

    i had this subclass :

    Ext.define('myChild' {
       extend : 'myParent',

    });
```

whenever i put this code in my subclass:

```
refs : [{
        ref : 'myReference',
        selector : 'myProduct'

    }],
```

i got this error during runtime :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'getMainForm'
```

i wonder if refs from the parent class were overriden by my child class....

what happened ? does it really overrides myParent's refs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you've found out yourself, there's no special treatment of the `refs` property so, yes, it does get overridden.

To augment it instead of replacing, you'll have to do it in the child classes constructor, like in this example:

```
Ext.define('myChild', {
    extend: 'myParent'
    ,constructor: function() {
        this.refs = (this.refs || []).concat([{
            ref: 'myReference',
            selector: 'myProduct'
        }]);
        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This really bugs me about Ext Controllers so today I had a go a fixing it, rixo solution works great but here is an alternative to extending every child class. Extend Ext.app.Controller instead using "onClassExtended" method

```
    /**
 * Extends Ext.app.Controller with the ability to have refs defined in
 * Controllers and any of subclasses.
 * Duplicate refs overwrite each other, last one in class hierarchy wins.
 */
Ext.define('App.Controller', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    //private make refs extensible by any subclasses
    onClassExtended : function(cls, data, hooks) {
        var onBeforeClassCreated = hooks.onBeforeCreated;
        hooks.onBeforeCreated = function(cls, data) {
            var me = this,
                name = Ext.getClassName(cls),
                prototype = cls.prototype,
                superCls = cls.prototype.superclass,
                thisRefs = data.refs || [],
                superRefs = superCls.refs || [],
                newRefs = [],
                i = 0;
            if (thisRefs.length > 0) {
                for (i=0; i < thisRefs.length; i++) {
                    if (typeof thisRefs[i] !== 'undefined') {
                        newRefs.push(thisRefs[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
            if (superRefs.length > 0) {
                for (i=0; i < superRefs.length; i++) {
                    if (typeof superRefs[i] !== 'undefined') {
                        newRefs.push(superRefs[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
            data.refs = newRefs;
            onBeforeClassCreated.call(me, cls, data, hooks);
        };
    }
});
```